# How to hide and show bottom bar dynamically in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I've making a app by flutter but some issues which hard to find make me hard
one of them is dynamic bottom bar

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return new Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: new BottomDrawer(
  ),
  drawer: new LeftDrawer(),
  endDrawer: new RightDrawer(),
```

just like this code I am using bottomNavigationBar.

what I want is that normally (just start app or do something) **bottom appbar(new BottomDrawer)** don't show and take a space,
 but when user slide up the bottom(just like a left, right drawer)
it show up and take the space
how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into [Redux](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_redux) or a similar Framework? On the Dart Conference 2018 was a good talk von [Brian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKXz3pUkw9A&t=1475s) when it can be helpfull to use it.

1) You can use a variable inside your Store like "isBottomNavigationBarDisplayed = false"

2) Write your Layout with a StoreConnector

3) Write a Reducer to change the variable when the user does sth. like scrolling upwards

4) redux automaticly rebuild the specific part of your app

Comment: thank you for fast comment and it was helpdful but i change the method by container widget anyway yhanks